# Yii2 API Youtube login and get logged in user's channel id

Tags: php, api, yii2, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In yii2 am trying to login via youtube, it is logging in successfully but am not able to get the response, here below my login code in view...

```
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$clientId = '##########################################';
$clientSecret = '################################';
$redirectURL = 'https://localhost/#####/frontend/web/site/youtube? 
authclient=youtube';

//Call Google API
$gClient->setApplicationName('Login to CodexWorld.com');
$gClient->setClientId($clientId);
$gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectURL);
$gClient->setScopes(array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
));
$authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();

$output = '<a href="'.filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL).'"><img 
src="images/glogin.png" alt=""> Log in with Youtube!</a>';
echo $output;
```

[login preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLnr.png)

After login it is successfully moving to mentioned controller action 'site/youtube'
under site controller not able to get the response, here below i am getting only code, not getting access code or some thing...

```
Array
(
[authclient] => youtube
    [code] => 
 4/AAAEwgSqI_OcRm00D55lLz9AZFLN_YSGa2w72Qb113P56ik0LEMr07hdsh6_OIbttnkQTVIci- 
 dk8C_6jJTlJAM
 )
```

below is my site/youtube code

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $code = $_GET['code];
}
```

kindly help to get user response...
[you tube login permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPsZF.png)

Comment: Are you following the implementation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps)?

Comment: yes i am following the same google sdk